# how to set text size using the selector?

Tags: android

I use a selector and I do not know how to set text size. Maybe I'm doing something wrong - help

arrow.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/green"></item>

</selector>
```

Comment: I have the same question with you but still can't find the answer :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use an selector under animator resources:

```
<!-- res/animator/text_size.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="0"
                android:propertyName="textSize"
                android:valueTo="18sp"
                android:valueType="floatType"/>
        </set>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="false">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="0"
                android:propertyName="textSize"
                android:valueTo="10sp"
                android:valueType="floatType"/>
        </set>
    </item>
</selector>
```

You can have 0 duration for jumping straight to the value or put a duration in there.

Then to use it set `android:stateListAnimator` on your view:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 3"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/text_size"/>
```

Comment: This is useful, however I found that using sp values in objectAnimator `valueTo/From` causes it to be converted to a float twice because `TextView.setTextSize(float)` treats the value as sp. Not specifying a unit keeps the text sizes consistent with the rest of the resources.

Comment: I don't follow, maybe write up as an answer.

Comment: Maybe this worked in 2017 mais it doesn't anymore in 2020, it says that `<objectAnimator> is not allowed here` and autocompletion is off. The app runs but the animator is ignored.

Answer (score -3):

Create your own `style.xml` and define the text style. And then set the style in your selector.

`style.xml`

```
<style name="myStyle">  
    <item name="android:textSize">9px</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

And in your selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          style="@style/myStyle" /> 
</selector>
```

Comment: Hi @Apurva, where to put the selector file? Is it in the drawable?

Comment: Does this really work? I get warning "Unknown attribute style". AFAIK Selectors only work with drawables and not styles.