# Android - change textSize based on button pressed/unpressed state

Tags: android

I have a button background that change drawable if the state is pressed or not. I'm able to change text color and background like below but I would like to change text size. How can I do it .XML side?

**drawable/button_selector.xml:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_pressed" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_unpressed" />
</selector>
```

**res/color/src_text:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false" android:color="@color/blue2"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/color_concrete"/>
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" 
android:color="@color/color_concrete"/>
<item android:color="@color/blue2" />
</selector>
```

**button:**

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/playButton"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:onClick="@{(v)->mainViewModel.playButtonClick(v)}"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:text="@string/play"
            android:textColor="@color/src_text"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:visibility="@{mainViewModel.observableVisibilityPlayButton ? v.VISIBLE : v.GONE}"/>
```

Comment: I don't think it is directly possible in there. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448663/how-to-set-text-size-using-the-selector) to see how to do this using animation selector.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using databinding you can probably create a BindingAdapter like following:

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("textSize")
fun bindTextSize(button: Button, size: Int) {
    
    if(button.isPressed())
       button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, size);
}
```

Also keep a MutableLiveData field in the viewmodel (size) and change the value according to your need.

```
<Button
            textSize="@{mainViewModel.size}
            android:id="@+id/playButton"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:onClick="@{(v)->mainViewModel.playButtonClick(v)}"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:text="@string/play"
            android:textColor="@color/src_text"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:visibility="@{mainViewModel.observableVisibilityPlayButton ? v.VISIBLE : v.GONE}"/>
```

Comment: Yes I can but the button is not a switch case, I?m simuling botton clicked animation, and I need to resize the text if the button is pressed in his state pressed and normal if not pressed

Comment: @DoctorWho Please see my edit, this should probably work.

Comment: In my viewModel I can define the int "size" but I can't get the button touch event. I need the touch event inside my viewmodel if I want to use databinding

Comment: Why can't you get the button touch event in your view model? You're already accessing that event `android:onClick="@{(v)->mainViewModel.playButtonClick(v)}"` In playButtonClick just change the size variable depending on your case.

Comment: Because click action change the fragment. If I touch button drawable/button_selector.xml and text color change as I want

Answer (score 0):

You can create subclass of Button and override onTouch method

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // button pressed, change textSize
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // button released, revert textSize
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: In which part can I override it?

Comment: You create class which extends from class Button (or AppCompatButton), in this class override method onTouch, like in example above, then use this class instead of Button